# Migrate on Premise Oracle DB of size 8TB to AWS RDS Oracle

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Customer has an Oracle 11g running on 2 nodes RAC on premise. The size the DB is 8TB. I need to migrate the Oracle DB from on premise to AWS RDS Oracle.

I shall use Data Pump and AWS DMS with CDC. Customer has a requirement of zero or near zero downtime during migration.

But how can I take the backup of 8TB to S3 from on premise and download it from S3 to AWS? S3 has a limitation on file size of 5TB.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using AWS snowball edge Devices

> Larger data migrations can include many terabytes of information. This process can be cumbersome due to network bandwidth limits or just the sheer amount of data. AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) can use Snowball Edge and Amazon S3 to migrate large databases more quickly than by other methods.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_LargeDBs.Process.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. AWS does not allow access to RDS file system. If I use AWS SnowBall then how can I copy the 8TB dump file to the Oracle Dump Dir in RDS?

Comment: @Arunava - did you get a solution for your query? We have a similar situation where we need to migrate around 80TB of data. but as per documentation 64 TB is mentioned as limit. So does that mean we need to migrate data in multiple batches 64TB at a time?

Answer (score 0):

AWS already has documentation on how to migrate from on premise `oracle` db to `AWS RDS`.
It has mentioned

> Database size limit: 64 TB

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/migrate-an-on-premises-oracle-database-to-amazon-rds-for-oracle.html

All the strategies to do the migration are mentioned in below pdf

https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-migrating-oracle-database-to-aws.pdf

For migrating large data to AWS, you can refer following docs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_LargeDBs.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Customer does not have direct connect. If I use Goldengate to migrate 8TB volume, then how long the initial 8TB transfer may take approximately over normal internet connection?